# How to sort a column based on length of data in it in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

As we all know general sorting is using order by. The sort I want to perform is different. I want the smallest length value in middle of table n the largest ones in top and bottom of it. One half should be descending and another half should be ascending. Can you guys help. It was an interview question.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. See eg below for ref:

Comment: column1 column2 sorted_length(from column2)
aa aaaaaaaaa   9
bb bbbbbbbb    8
cc ccccccc     7
dd ddddd       5
ee eeee        4
ff ff          2
gg gggg        4
hh hhhhh       5
ii iiiiii      6
jj jjjjjjj     7
kk kkkkkkkk    8

Answer (score 9):

This is one way:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(YourColumn))
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RN%2, (CASE WHEN RN%2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)*RN DESC
```

Comment: The second criterion could also be rewritten in a less clear but more concise way: `(1 - RN % 2 * 2) * RN DESC`.

Answer (score 2):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(ID INT, Value VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
(1 , 'A'),
(2 , 'AB'),
(3 , 'ABC'),
(4 , 'ABCD'),
(5 , 'ABCDE'),
(6 , 'ABCDEF'),
(7 , 'ABCDEFG'),
(8 , 'ABCDEFGI'),
(9 , 'ABCDEFGIJ'),
(10 ,'ABCDEFGIJK')
```

### Query

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT * 
      ,NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY LEN(Value) DESC) rn
FROM @Table )
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN LEN(Value) END DESC
         ,CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN LEN(Value) END ASC
```

### Result

```
╔════╦════════════╦════╗
║ ID ║   Value    ║ rn ║
╠════╬════════════╬════╣
║ 10 ║ ABCDEFGIJK ║  1 ║
║  9 ║ ABCDEFGIJ  ║  1 ║
║  8 ║ ABCDEFGI   ║  1 ║
║  7 ║ ABCDEFG    ║  1 ║
║  6 ║ ABCDEF     ║  1 ║
║  1 ║ A          ║  2 ║
║  2 ║ AB         ║  2 ║
║  3 ║ ABC        ║  2 ║
║  4 ║ ABCD       ║  2 ║
║  5 ║ ABCDE      ║  2 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════╝
```

Comment: This way makes sure that the top results have the lengthy rows and the last half are the shorter ones.

Comment: @Lamak Can you please elaborate your claim ?

Comment: Sure. Your result ordered the half with the maximum length all first (in this case the lengths 10, 9, 8, 7, 6), and then the other half. But op said s/he wants **the largests in top and bottom**, not the largest on top, and the rest on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short approach that would ge t you started:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1000 number
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE type = 'P' and number >0
)
SELECT number,  row_number() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN number %2 = 1 THEN number ELSE -(number) END) pos 
FROM cte
```

Comment: This [works well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38449) on a sequence with no gaps or duplicates. Now imagine [if all values are even](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38450)...

Comment: the cte is just to get a list of numbers. It might be neccessary to apply ROW_NUMBER to the original table to get a sorted list. This would also work for all values are even and for all values are equal, too. I decided to focus on sorting a numbered list, not the numbering process itself. Would have been different if the OP would have decided to provide some sample data... Lazyness on both sides, I'd say...

Comment: I don't see an `ORDER BY` in the query. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: The ORDER BY is part of the ROW_NUMBER function.